# ASP.NET MVC Web API Models that are not tied to query string parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I know how to create a model class that mirrors query string variables so that when it comes into my Web API controller action, the model is populated.

However, is there a way to make it so that I'm not locked into the query string variable names as the properties on my model class?

Example:

```
public class MyModel {
    public string o {get;set;}
}

public class MyController {
    public string Get(MyModel model) {

    }
}
```

Then, if my query string looks like:
GET http://domain.com/?o=12345

Is there a way to name that model property "Order" or something instead of "o" and then have it populated with the value from "o="?

Comment: 2 completely different answers - can't wait to try them out and figure out which one to mark!  Love stack!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom model binder that will bind data to model as you wish. To use it you should:

```
public string Get([ModelBinder(typeof(MyComplexTypeModelBinder))]MyModel model)
{
...
}
```

To create custom model binder you can inherit from IModelBinder or from DefaultModelBinder.

```
public class MyComplexTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

  public Object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                          ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
     if (bindingContext == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

     // Create the model instance (using the ctor you like best)
     var obj = new MyComplexType();

     // Set properties reading values from registered value providers
     obj.Order = FromPostedData<string>(bindingContext, "o");
     ...
     return obj;
}


private T FromPostedData<T>(ModelBindingContext context, String key)
{
   // Get the value from any of the input collections
   ValueProviderResult result;
   context.ValueProvider.TryGetValue(key, out result);

   // Set the state of the model property resulting from 
   context.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, result);
   // Return the value converted (if possible) to the target type
   return (T) result.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this scenario is custom `IValueProvider`. This ASP.NET MVC extension point is the correct place, where we can bridge the `QueryString` keys into Model.Property names. In comparison with `ModelBinder`, this will target exactly what we need *(while not introducing later issues, when even other value providers (FORM) accidently contains that key...)*

There is good tutorial how to introduce the custom `IValueProvider`:

- http://donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-create-a-custom-Value-Provider-for-MVC.aspx

And there is an simple example which is able to provide values for Model "Order" property, coming as QueryString "o" key:

**Factory**

```
// Factory
public class MyValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
  public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext ctx)
  {
    return new MyValueProvider(ctx);
  }
}
```

**Provider**

```
// Provider
class MyValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
  protected HttpRequestBase Request { get; set; }    
  public MyValueProvider(ControllerContext ctx)
  {
    Request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
  }

  // our custom logic to test QueryString keys, and expected prefixes
  public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
  {
    var containsSpecial =
      "Order".Equals(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      && Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("o"
                    , StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    return containsSpecial;
  }

  // Handling "Order" key
  public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
  {
    if (!ContainsPrefix(key))
    {
      return null;
    }
    var values = Request.QueryString.GetValues("o");

    if (values.Any())
    {
      return new ValueProviderResult(values, values.First()
                                    , CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And in the `global.asax` we have to inject it:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyValueProviderFactory());
  ...
```